# Simple applications of Atiyah-Bott localization

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, examples

I am looking for some simple and concrete -- but still non-trivial and illustrative -- applications of Atiyah-Bott localization in the context of equivariant cohomology.

Do you know any good ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to read [A Lefschetz Fixed Point Formula for Elliptic Complexes: II. Applications](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1970721), Atiyah and Bott, Ann. of Math., Vol. 88, No. 3 (Nov., 1968), pp. 451-491